# AccessViolationException at Marshal.Copy when capturing video image

Tags: c#, interop

I've been using the snippet below to capture a video frame from webcams for about 12 years, and it's always worked without problems.

```
var videoHeader = new API32.VIDEOHDR();
videoHeader = (API32.VIDEOHDR)API32.GetStructure(lpVHdr, videoHeader);
var videoData = new byte[videoHeader.dwBytesUsed];
Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(videoHeader.lpData), videoData, 0, videoHeader.dwBytesUsed);
```

After upgrading the project to .NET 4.6.1, it started throwing **AccessViolationException** at `Marshal.Copy()`.  Tests show that it works in .NET 3.5, but throws in .NET 4 and up.

I've seen similar posts where the problem was trying to copy more bits than were in the source, but that's not the problem here.

Is this expected behavior in .NET 4?

**Update:** Adding the VIDEOHDR structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct VIDEOHDR
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int lpData;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int dwBufferLength;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int dwBytesUsed;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int dwTimeCaptured;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int dwUser;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int dwFlags;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public int[] dwReserved;
}
```

Comment: Is there a different in you project between 32 and 64 bits at all? What does your structure look like?

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins, no difference in target platform, and I updated to show the structure.